# Random number generator which produces same order for each seed, highest value not higher than cycle length & no close form for index or value

Tags: algorithm, random

Full question:
Is there a (pseudo) random number generator which produces same value order for each seed, highest value not (much) higher than cycle length & no close form to get I'th value or index of a value?

More details:

- Cycle length is the number of elements until it starts again
- All numbers of that cycle should not be much higher than the cycle length itself. Let's say <100 times.
- All cycle numbers can't be stored by a usual computer
- random number equations should not allow to produce the n'th value after the seed or determine the index of a given value. Only way of computation should be the iterative way. Even if you know the source code and run-time variables
- all seeds produce a cycle with same length. Each should have the same random value order. E.g. [1 4 2 3 5 ...] if seed is 1 and [2 3 5 ...] is seed is 2 (seed don't need to be equal to first random value). Optional instead of one they produce a small amount of different cycles. Let's say <100.

Do you know any random generator/algorithm which can do this? 
(don't need to be perfect random values)

Comment: Can you explain why you need these properties? In any decent random number generator you will not be able to observe the the full cycle length, because it is simply going to be too long. Then you wont be able to determine whether you are on the same cycle for different seeds either. So I don't see how these properties could matter.

Comment: Your "iterative only" requirement appears to be a contradiction based in the fundamentals of computability.

Comment: @uneven_mark for some RNG you can predict the cycle length without computing each number. I need about 10^20 numbers with number order equal but not predictable for index. So they are equal at each user PC (Or if multiple cycle, equal at some user PC). Because of size generating all first and storing in program is not an option. The numbers are assigned to a limited number of identities so the value range need to be known before.

Comment: @J.Doe Yes the length may be predictable, but what I mean is that the length will be so large that you cannot possible iterate through the whole cycle or even a fraction of it. For example the Mersenne Twister has a period of `2^19937-1` which is physically impossible to fully iterate. Then assume that the RNG actually has multiple independent cycles. If you start at a random initial state, how are you ever going to be able to tell whether they are part of the same cycle (absent feasible mathematical attacks on the particular RNG)? So then I am left wondering why the number of cycles matters.

Comment: You say, "all seeds produce a cycle with the same length. Each the same order of random values." The wording is unclear and your example doesn't clarify. If a seed of 0 produces `[1,3,2,5,7,4,6, ...]` do you want a seed of 1 to produce `[3,2,5,7,4,6, ...]`? And a seed of 2 to produce `[2,5,7,4,6, ...]`?

Comment: Also, you say, "random number equations should now allow ..." Did you mean *not* rather than *now*?

Comment: @uneven_mark Mersenne Twister was build to have some long period. I'm pretty sure it can be adapted to a smaller period length. However afaik the number order is also different among different seeds. So can't use this. I'm looking for a period of about 2^64. One cycle should be shared among many users. A single user can't compute all values but all together can (thats target aim for use case).

Comment: @JimMischel could be. Lets say my period is only 8 numbers e.g. [1,3,2,5,7,4,6,0]. If seed is 0 order is [1,3,2,5,7,4,6,0,1,3,2,...] if seed 1 order is [3,2,5,7,4,6,0,1,3,2,5,...] But there don't need to exist any connection with the seed value and the shift or starting/end value of the cycle. So e.g. seed 2 could also be [7,4,6,0,1,3,2,5,7,4,6,0,...]. &ty for the hint, it should be 'not' and not 'now', edited it

Comment: There's [Xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift), which has a period of (2^128)-1. However, discussion of [Linear Feedback Shift Registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register), of which Xorshift is an example, indicates that cracking may be easier than you'd like. Intuitively, though, I'd expect any system that returns numbers in the same order (just starting at a different place in the sequence) to be relatively easy to crack.

Comment: @JimMischel LFSR are very easy to crack [jump ahead](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/60634/lfsr-jump-ahead-algorithm). Generating the hash value of a hash value of a hash value ... generates the same order but can be hard to crack. Problem with this is the not predicable short cycle length and many cycles with inconsistent size exists. It would work if a (fast) function exists which can tell if a random number is part of the cycle. But this don't exists afaik.

Comment: Something else that might work is a [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse). I've never really thought about using it as a random number generator before. It's reasonably random looking. Don't know how easy it would be to crack.

Comment: @JimMischel sry, for late response. Did some research about your suggestion for one example which use this named [Inversive congruentia _generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_congruential_generator). Sadly there is also a close from to compute i'th element. But ty for link, learned some more.

Comment: As I said previously, I'm not convinced there is a solution to your problem. I think you have conflicting requirements that can't be resolved.